# ATmega128A - Assembly RET doesn't return but starts again

Tags: assembly, return

I've got problems with RET. It doesn't return to the point, where `delay`was called. The stack pointer's value isn't changed during `delay` and is set to `0x0000FFFE`.

```
.include "m128adef.inc"

//f = 7,3728*10^6 Hz ~ 135 ns

.def oneDiod = r16
.def secondDiod = r17
.def ones = r18
.def i1 = r19
.def i2 = r20
.def i3 = r21
.def i4 = r22
.def i5 = r23

ldi ones, 0xff
ldi oneDiod, 0b01111111
ldi secondDiod, 0b10111111

out ddrc, ones


loop:

out portc, oneDiod

call delay

out portc, secondDiod

call delay
rjmp loop

delay:

ldi i3, 37
p3: ldi i2, 0xff
p2: ldi i1, 0xff
p1: dec i1
brne p1 
nop

dec i2
brne p2
nop

dec i3
brne p3
nop

ldi i5, 152
p5: ldi i4, 0xff
p4: dec i4
brne p4
nop

dec i5
brne p5
nop

ret
```

`delay` is mostly a great time-waster, which provides work for uC for about one second. I can debug it to the last NOP instruction, when I step over 2 times, RET goes to the 1st line.

Comment: Which architecture are you programming for?

Comment: atmega 128a, microcontroller

Comment: How much physical memory does your microcontroller have? Are you sure address 0x0000FFFE is mapped to physical memory?

Comment: Yes it is. Btw this is the value shown where in avrstudio  things like flags, registers, counters are shown

Comment: Next time please state clearly what assembly is your question about.

Comment: @Embid123 Just because the stackpointer is 0x0000FFFE, doesn't necessarily mean there is any memory at that address. A standard ATmega128A without external data SRAM has no memory there. CALL would write its return address into a void, and RET would read an undefined return address; possibly zero.

Comment: I set stack pointer to ramend and it works now. Thanks for help